# Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: string, perl, initialization, concatenation

I wrote a script today. The purpose of this is to automatically add new virtual host to Apache. The script should be executed using this command:

```
./new_vhost.pl --add --domain google.com --client google.
```

However, it doesn't work well instead it throws me errors

> Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string

Have you guys experienced this before? I was thinking the cause was the '.' in google.com though I am not really sure about it. I'm still searching for answers on Google but unfortunately nothing could help me fix this.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Cwd;
use POSIX "strftime";

my $dir = getcwd;
my $conf = 'test.conf';

my $domain = undef;
my $client = undef;
my $help = undef;
my $ltime = undef;

if (-e $conf) {
        sub usage {
                die "Usage: $0 [--add | --remove] [--domain google.com] [--client google].\n";
        }

        usage unless @ARGV > 3;
        GetOptions (
                'add' => \&add_vhost,
#               'remove' => \&rem_vhost,
                'domain=s' => \$domain,
                'client=s' => \$client,
                'help' => \&usage
        ) || usage;

        $domain = lc($domain);
        $client = uc($client);
        $ltime = localtime;

        sub add_vhost {
                open (CONF, ">>$conf") || die "ERROR: unable to open $conf.\n";
                print CONF "#***** Start of configuration for $domain. *****#";
                print CONF "\n# Domain: $domain\n";
                print CONF "# Client: $client\n";
                print CONF "# Date: $ltime\n";
                print CONF "<VirtualHost *:1111>\n";
                print CONF "    ServerAdmin admin\@$domain\n";
                print CONF "    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/$domain\n";
                print CONF "    ServerName $domain\n";
                print CONF "    ServerAlias www.$domain\n";
                print CONF "    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/$domain/$domain-error_log\n";
                print CONF "    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/$domain/$domain-access_log common\n";
                print CONF "</VirtualHost>\n";
                print CONF "#***** End of configuration for $domain. *****#\n";
                close CONF;
                if ($? != 0) {
                        die "Error: unable to create a new configuration.\n";
                } else {
                        print "OK: new configuration for $domain has been added.\n";
                }
        }
} else {
        die "ERROR: $conf not found.\n";

}
```

Error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 37.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 38.
Use of uninitialized value $client in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 39.
Use of uninitialized value $ltime in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 40.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 42.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 43.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 44.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 45.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 46.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 46.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 49.
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string at ./new_vhost.pl line 54.
OK: new configuration for  has been added.
```

The test.conf after running the script.

```
#***** Start of configuration for . *****#
# Domain:
# Client:
# Date:
<VirtualHost *:1111>
    ServerAdmin admin@
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName
    ServerAlias www.
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd//-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd//-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
#***** End of configuration for . *****#
```

But I was expecting something like this...

```
#***** Start of configuration for google.com. *****#
# Domain: google.com
# Client: GOOGLE
# Date: Tue Apr  8 17:27:39 2014
<VirtualHost *:1111>
    ServerAdmin admin@google.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/google.com
    ServerName google.com
    ServerAlias www.google.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/google.com/google.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/google.com/google.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
#***** End of configuration for google.com. *****#
```

Comment: This script is working fine for me, except you're never calling `sub add_vhost`. I suspect it isn't the script you're running.

Comment: Hi @M42! The first time I ran the script, it did not work. I just realized that I've forgotten to declare a new undefined variable `add` and I mistakenly pointed the `add` argument to `add_vhost` sub which executes immediately without getting the information I've passed to `$domain` and `$client`. I'm happy it's running fine now. Thanks for your time as well! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `GetOptions` is trying to call your `add_vhost`, the variables `$domain` and `$client` may not be initialized.

You could change your code to

```
my $add = undef;

...

GetOptions (
    'add' => \$add,
...

if ($add) {
    add_vhost();
}

...
```

By the way, you better move your definition of `add_vhost` out of that conditional statement, and pass those information such as `$domain` as arguments to `add_vhost` instead of using global variables.

Comment: Cool! This works great! Thanks for the answer. It is working now. As advised, I have moved my `add_vhost` out of the conditional statement. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Cwd;
use POSIX "strftime";

my $dir = getcwd;
my $conf = 'test.conf';

my $domain = undef;
my $client = undef;
my $help = undef;
my $ltime = undef;
my $to_add_vhost = undef;

if (-e $conf) {
        sub usage {
                die "Usage: $0 [--add | --remove] [--domain google.com] [--client google].\n";
        }

        usage unless @ARGV > 3;
        GetOptions (
                'add' => \$to_add_vhost,
#               'remove' => \&rem_vhost,
                'domain=s' => \$domain,
                'client=s' => \$client,
                'help' => \&usage
        ) || usage;

        $domain = lc($domain);
        $client = uc($client);
        $ltime = localtime;

    &add_vhost if (defined $to_add_vhost);

        sub add_vhost {
                open (CONF, ">>$conf") || die "ERROR: unable to open $conf.\n";
                print CONF "#***** Start of configuration for $domain. *****#";
                print CONF "\n# Domain: $domain\n";
                print CONF "# Client: $client\n";
                print CONF "# Date: $ltime\n";
                print CONF "<VirtualHost *:1111>\n";
                print CONF "    ServerAdmin admin\@$domain\n";
                print CONF "    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/$domain\n";
                print CONF "    ServerName $domain\n";
                print CONF "    ServerAlias www.$domain\n";
                print CONF "    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/$domain/$domain-error_log\n";
                print CONF "    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/$domain/$domain-access_log common\n";
                print CONF "</VirtualHost>\n";
                print CONF "#***** End of configuration for $domain. *****#\n";
                close CONF;
                if ($? != 0) {
                        die "Error: unable to create a new configuration.\n";
                } else {
                        print "OK: new configuration for $domain has been added.\n";
                }
        }
} else {
        die "ERROR: $conf not found.\n";

}
```

Comment: This works great too. I'm also saving this workaround just in case. Thanks, Morad! I appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd advise some style changes to clean up your code.

- When checking for an error, `die` immediately instead of after an `else`.
- You can declare your parameters for `GetOptions` in the actual subroutine call to simplify things.
- Considering using a HERE_DOC when printing a big block of text.
- Your error checking on `@ARGV` before calling `GetOptions` is unnecessary.  Let `GetOptions` handle that by having your required parameters.  As it is, you'll currently fail under a valid calling method `--domain=value --client=value' because only 2 elements will be in`@ARGV` versus 4.

This cleans up your code to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Getopt::Long;
use Cwd;
use POSIX "strftime";

my $dir = getcwd;
my $conf = 'test.conf';

die "ERROR: $conf not found.\n" if ! -e $conf;

sub usage {
    die "Usage: $0 [--add | --remove] [--domain google.com] [--client google].\n";
}

GetOptions(
    'add'      => \my $add,
#   'remove'   => \&rem_vhost,
    'domain=s' => \my $domain,
    'client=s' => \my $client,
    'help'     => \&usage
) or usage();

$domain = lc($domain);
$client = uc($client);
my $ltime = localtime;

if ($add) {
    add_vhost();
}

sub add_vhost {
    open my $fh, '>>', $conf;

    print $fh <<"END_CONF";
#***** Start of configuration for $domain. *****#
# Domain: $domain
# Client: $client
# Date: $ltime
<VirtualHost *:1111>
    ServerAdmin admin\@$domain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/$domain
    ServerName $domain
    ServerAlias www.$domain
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/$domain/${domain}-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/$domain/${domain}-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
#***** End of configuration for $domain. *****#
END_CONF

    if ($? != 0) {
        die "Error: unable to create a new configuration.\n";
    } else {
        print "OK: new configuration for $domain has been added.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Miller! This looks good. Thanks for your advise. I'll keep this in mind. :)

Comment: @DV A downvote 4 months later without a comment is not constructive.  The advice and code I shared is useful as far as I know, but if something is not then actual feedback would be of service to not just me but anyone checking back at this thread.  As it is, I'm the only person who has thus far cast an upvote on this question (for Lee's answer), so I'd also recommend using UV's to reward the better answer if you think there is one.